# how to allow ec2 health check through .htaccess while redirecting to https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, elastic-load-balancer

I'm trying to create an .htaccess file that does the following:

1 Allows the EC2 health check URL to be hit without redirecting to https
2 Redirects all non-https traffic to https
3 Redirect calls to / to /auth/app/public/app (using https)

Items 2 and 3 work fine, but quickly the healthcheck fails and the server no longer responds.  Here's the content of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

#one attempt that didn't work
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my\.domain\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/healthcheck.html$
#RewriteRule ^ http://my.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#another attempt that didn't work
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/healthcheck.html$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA]

#this works
RewriteRule ^$ https://my.domain.com/auth/app/public/app/ [L]

#this works
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://my.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The first two commented-out attempts are from examples I found at https://serverfault.com/questions/470015/how-should-i-configure-my-elb-health-check-when-using-namevirtualhosts-and-redir 
and https://serverfault.com/questions/470015/how-should-i-configure-my-elb-health-check-when-using-namevirtualhosts-and-redir/597541#597541

Please let me know if you have any suggestions how I can get this working.

Comment: I’d try with a simple `RewriteRule ^healthcheck\.html$ - [L]` – when the requested URL is `healthcheck.html`, then don’t rewrite anything (`-`), and make this the last rule. That should not need any additional RewriteConds.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply.  Before I read that, I found another post that provided a solution that is working for me.  I simply added another condition to not apply the https redirect rule if the url was that of my health check page.  Here is the working version of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ https://my.domain.com/auth/app/public/app/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/healthcheck\.html$
RewriteRule ^ https://my.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```